# "File not processed yet"

Tags: node.js, api, express

I am currently trying to retrieve the data from the file that I processed using the docparser API, however when I get the Document ID after I send the file I try to retrieve it and I get a status code of 400 with the error stating "File not processed yet".

```js
// Upload Route
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {
  const file = req.file;
  const stream = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/../client/public/uploads/${file.filename}`);

  
  if (file == null) {
    return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No file uploaded' });
  }

  try {
    let result = await client.uploadFileByStream(parserID, stream);
    let docID = result.id;
    console.log(docID);
    let parsedData = await client.getResultsByDocument(parserID,docID, {format: 'object'});
    console.log(parsedData);
    return res.status(200).send(parsedData); 
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err)
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'An error occurred' })
  }

});
```

Any suggestions as to why this could be happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Well without knowing DocParser this strongly suggest that you are calling the results too early and you need to wait till the file is finished.

Comment: Yeah that was the issue, I was making the request to fast so I just added a function that would delay the call which worked